# How to test null return using Mockito thenReturn(Single.just(null))

Tags: android, tdd, mockito, rx-android

I want to test the condition when single return null

```
when(repository.getSubLocations(ID)).thenReturn(Single.just(null));
```

but it gives me error

```
at io.reactivex.internal.functions.ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(ObjectHelper.java:39)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution instead of doing this

```
when(repository.getSubLocations(ID)).thenReturn(Single.just(null));
```

I do this

```
when(repository.getSubLocations(ID)).thenReturn(Single.just(SOME_DATA).map(data -> null));
```

so now I can successfully test null condition